# 別に恥ずかしいとか思わない。別に I dont get it

Tags: grammar, polarity-items

別に恥ずかしいとか思わない。

What is 別に? I didnt get it. Ive already read some articles about it, but sill..

The first article I read. I learned the meaning of it, which can be "not really, not particularly", and that the verb has to be in the negative form. Example "それはべつにわるいことでもない。""That's not particularly a bad thing."

But I can't get it here.

Comment: Can you post your thoughts on what it means based on the articles you've read?

Comment: Can you explain why you don't think "not particularly" works as a translation here?  Is there additional context that makes you think this way? What do you think the rest of the sentence means? Information like this helps people to give you a better answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

別に by itself means "particularly", "in particular", "specially", etc. It's a [negative polarity item](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/16060/5010), so it is almost always used in a negative sentence. 別に(～ない) is used when something is not special nor of particular interest.

> 別に恥ずかしいとか思わない。
>   I don't think it's embarrassing *in particular*.