# What is the difference between (ない)わけではない and (ない)ことはない?

Tags: grammar, word-choice, nuances

As I understand, they are both very close in terms of meaning.

E.g.

> 私は歌を歌えない**わけではない**が、人前で歌うのは恥ずかしい。
> 私は歌を歌えない**ことはない**が、人前で歌うのは恥ずかしい。

Both sentences would mean: "It's not that I cannot sing, it's just that I get embarrassed in front of others."

I'm pretty sure there is a slight difference in nuance, that I can't quite grasp yet.

Is it a matter of opposing the belief of someone that you can't? (while the other is plainly a statement?)

Comment: する doesn't work like "(when I) do" in this context. See: [Can する substitute a previously used verb?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/94444/5010)

Comment: I'm a bit confused, was this comment meant for another post?

Comment: I wanted to point out "人前ですると" made little sense here. You wrote すると because you thought it's a correct way of saying "if I *do*", right?

Comment: Oh, I just saw the original... It was a random copy-paste example, now that you mention it it makes little sence indeed. I didn't even bother to read it to be honest, I focused mainly on the difference between the 2 points. Thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is very little difference, and they are interchangeable most of the time. Still, I feel the speaker is more aware of the previous context when わけではない is used. That is, a sentence using わけではない tends to have a nuance of "that is not to say", "that doesn't mean" or "I'm not saying". ことはない is a relatively "plain" double-negative sentence.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for, but -タ form seems to behave differently for the two constructions. As I see it, なかったことはない coincides with another construction -たことがある, which takes precedence. なかったわけではない doesn't have the same problem.

> 私は歌が歌えなかったことはないが、人前で歌うのは恥ずかしかった。

Most people will read this as "I have never been unable to sing" (="I always could"). The other interpretation ("It's not that I couldn't sing"="I could to some extent") might not be impossible, but it would be much harder to read that way.

Whereas, the same doesn't happen when you change ないわけではない to なかったわけではない.

> 私は歌が歌えなかったわけではないが、人前で歌うのは恥ずかしかった。

The only difference from the original sentence is that it describes a past event.

Comment: Thanks for the Insight! Indeed, as @naruto mentioned before, ことはない is a plain negation so whether ない・なかった comes before, it is a simple "plain" double-negation. To my estimation so far it seems like わけではない is more close to: "It's not that...". It's as if you are explaining or disagreeing with the other person's guess/estimation. In that case the Past-Sentence example puts things in their place clearly.

Comment: As I see it, the main issue in what I argued is a conflict with another construction -たことがある. I edited my answer to clarify.