# Question about a possible meaning of "この先も"

Tags: translation

So in English, you can say sentences like-

"I think I'm still gonna fail the test even after this." (With the "this" being a long study session or something")

or
"Do you think I can still make the team even after this." (With the "this" being an injury or something)

or
"It still might've worked out, even after all this." (With the "this" being steps you took for it to work out.)

In some cases, can "この先も" mean "Even after this" in this sense?

I looked at some example sentences with this phrase, and it was translated like "in the future" or "forever," and that made sense, but honestly I couldn't find enough example sentences to rule out any other possible nuance in certain cases.

The reason I'm asking this in the first place is because I'm trying to translate a song for practice and this sort of nuance seems to make sense in the lyrics.

The lyrics in question with my attempted translation- (Please note, the translation is just for personal use/learning sake, and so it's not that polished.)

```
泣いても泣いても流せない　傷があるよ
```

There are wounds that you can’t wash away, even if you cry, even if you cry

```
誰にも気づかれることなど　この先もきっと無いけど
```

They’ll surely go unnoticed even after this, but

(lit. The thing of people noticing them, even after a point with X action, will surely not happen)

```
薄っぺらいこんな歌でも　もし良ければ
```

If you don’t mind, let even this sort of shallow song,

```
あなたのその傷も隠させてよ
```

hide those wounds of yours

So I'm thinking that the "this" refers to the action of the person letting the song hide their wounds.

Of course, if "この先も" were to be used in this sense, it would literally mean something more like "even after this point in time (in which somebody did X action.)" In other words, the English expression is more direct, with the "this" directly referencing the actions taken.

Okay, sorry if I'm just tired and missing something obvious. This line is sort of giving me issues because, if this nuance really isn't present, I don't really know how this line fits in with the other lines. Like, it's odd to just plainly say that X will definitely go unnoticed and then offer to hide it. The "even after this" nuance adds the meaning of the singer just wanting to help in some way, even if it's futile; so it gives the line a purpose.

Anyway, any feedback/help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

この先も is a set phrase that refers to a long period of time from now ("also for the next years/months to come", "beyond this point, too", etc.). When you say この先も, この always refers to **now** or **here**, not a particular event. If you have a specific "this" (e.g., a long study session) in mind, don't use この先.

> 誰にも気づかれることなど　この先もきっと無い
> (It's been unnoticed so far and) surely it will remain unnoticed also in the future

The [lyrics](https://ameblo.jp/yuruyuru-1955/entry-12614479812.html) roughly mean "Everyone has invisible wounds, but my song can heal them, so let me heal yours with my song".

To translate "even after this", how about:

> これでもまだ試験に落ちると思う。
> これだけやってもやっぱり試験に落ちると思う。
> I think I'm still gonna fail the test even after this.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the response. So in just this part 誰にも気づかれる does  誰にも mean nobody or anybody?

Comment: @MastahxGraffiti That's a [negative polarity item](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/16060/5010). 誰にも by itself means "anybody" but it's always used with some form of negation.