# Negative in Japanese, but positive in English translation. Why? 俺は自分が生き残ることしか考えていなかった‌

Tags: usage, negation, polarity-items

> 俺は自分が生き残ることしか考えていなかった‌.
> the only thing I thought ‌about was surviving.‌
> ore ha jibun ga ikinokoru koto shika kangaeteinakatta‌.

I don't really understand why in Japanese it uses 考えて in the negative, since that in English would mean the opposite of what it is trying to say (the only thing I wasn't thinking, was about surviving). Why is that?

Comment: Do you understand the [...しか...ない](https://www.learn-japanese-adventure.com/japanese-expressions-dake-shika.html)  grammar structure?  This is the key to why this is translated in the positive.

Comment: *I didn’t think anything but …* is a negative sentence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was hoping someone would find what I haven't been able to find:  namely a duplicate of this question.  But the only questions/answers I can find are related to various particular scenarios.

There are various constructions similar to ...しか...ない
in Japanese.  Some call these [*negative polarity items.*](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/1565/4875)  The linked answer gives some other examples in both English and Japanese that may help you wrap you mind around the concept.  And as @aguijonazo mentioned in the comments, this particular construction can at times be reworded into a corresponding negative construction in English.

But, here I'd just like to mention the following:  There are various ways of saying *only* in Japanese.  The ...しか...ない construct is one of them.

> I eat *only apples*.
>
> りんごしか食べません。

> I only read Japanese novels.
>
> 日本語の小説しかよまない。

> I could only get there by train.
>
> 電車でしかいけなった。

しか is applied to the noun phrase (after a particle if there is one) that is being restricted.  In English, the translations can be a bit more lose.

Other ways of expressing *only* in Japanese can be formed using だけ and ばかり.