# How does 一回だって in this sentence mean "not even once" when there's no negative?

Tags: translation, negation, polarity-items

I came across this sentence watching March Comes In Like a Lion. I'll transcribe it to the best of my ability: ([here's the episode though](https://www.crunchyroll.com/march-comes-in-like-a-lion/episode-16-chapter-32-running-through-the-night-chapter-33-middle-of-the-slope-728011), and the quote happens at 5:46)

> 僕【ぼく】は遠慮【えんりょ】することにばかり気【き】をつけて、実【じつ】は彼女【かのじょ】たちに頼【たよ】られたことって**一回【いっかい】だって**。そうだ。**一回【いっかい】だって**。

This is the translation in the subtitles:

> I'd been careful not to presume on their kindness, but actually, they've **never** depended on me for anything. That's right. **Not even once**.

My best guess is that it's basically an incomplete sentence, with some implied conclusion that makes so much sense / is so common that it just gets dropped? If that's not the case, I just don't get where the "not" and "never" would come from. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I can't view the video.  `Sorry, this video is not available in your region!` だって。

Comment: Perhaps 「一回だってない」?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The だって in your example means:

> だって 〘副助〙
> ❹《最小を表す語に付いて、下に打ち消しの語を伴って》全面的否定を表す。…も。
> 「こんな会社は一日**だって**我慢でき**ない**」
> 「わずか**だって**ミスは許され**ない**」
> (明鏡国語辞典)

Used in this sense, だって(≈も) is always followed by negation. eg

> 「一回**だってない**。」「一度**もない**。」
> （*「一回だってある。」 *「一度もある。」 ← incorrect)

And you can see 一回だって/一度も "even once" as a [negative polarity item](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/16060/9831). From the linked answer:

> Unlike English, Japanese is verb-final, and negation usually comes toward the end of a sentence. Many Japanese NPIs appear early, and they're often signals that a negative predicate is coming up:
>
> > ​ 7a. ​ 決して忘れたりしない。
> > ​ 7b. *決して忘れたりする。
>
> In many cases, this signal is strong enough that you can leave out the actual part of the predicate containing the negation (as long as it can be inferred from context):
> ​
>
> > 8a. ちっとも変わらない。
> > ​8b. ちっとも。

Similarly, with 一回だって/一度も the predicate containing the negation can often be left out:

> 「行ったことあったっけ？」　-- 「一度も。」/「一回も。」
> "Have you been there before?" -- "No, not even once."
> 「疑ったことなど、これまでに一度だって！」
> "I have never doubted even once!"

Answer (score 3):

See [デジタル大辞泉（小学館）](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E3%81%A0%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6/)

> ［係助］《断定の助動詞「だ」に係助詞「とて」の付いた「だとて」の音変化という》名詞・副詞、一部の助詞に付く。「でも」に似るが、語調がより強い。
>
> 疑問・不定を表す語、または、数量・程度を表す語に付いて、例外なくそうである意を表す。…でも。…も。「だれだって知っている」「一度だって姿を見せない」

だって has multiple meanings. In this usage, there is a strong sense of "even that" where that could refer to an amount, a degree, or anything along those lines. 「一度だってないのだ！」= (literally) there is not even once = Not even once (something has happened)

ない is omitted in that line from the anime, but I am not sure how commonly this kind of omission occurs.