# Pitch Accent of 何にも

Tags: pitch-accent

I'm trying to understand the pitch of the sentence fragment

> それであたし何にもしてないのに...

In particular "何にも" is giving me trouble. When I enter this word into [OJAD](https://www.gavo.t.u-tokyo.ac.jp/ojad/phrasing/index), it shows as Atamadaka:

> [image]

But dictionaries are reporting it as all sorts of things:

> [image]

Moreover, it looks like the reading of "何" from "何にも" can be either なん (slang?) or なに. If the latter, the pitch changes again?

> [image]

Finally, is "何にも" distinct from 何 + に + も? If not, an accepted pronuncation of 何 seems to be "naNI" (Heiban), so wouldn't a third acceptable pronuncation be "naNINImo", since the first particle would raise (since 何 is being treated as Heiban), and the second particle would lower (since second successive particles lower, as a rule)?

> [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least when 何にも is used as a [negative polarity item](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/16060/5010) (which is almost always the case), it is always pronounced as heiban (なんにも【LHHH】/なににも【LHHH】). That result from OJAC seems confusing to me.

See also: [The pitch accent of なんの意味もない](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/94884/5010)

But なににも【HLLL】 may appear in rare cases where it is used as an equivalent of 何にでも/何に対しても (e.g., なににも【HLLL】使えるソース "sauce you can use for whatever/everything").

Comment: It looks like 何にも is being used as a negative polarity item in 「それであたし何にもしてないのに」, no? So it should be pronounced Heiban?

Comment: @George Can you elaborate? Do you mean you know a video where a native speaker clearly used atamadaka for 何にも(してない)?

Comment: The source of this line is at 2m32s of [Episode 1 of Death Note](https://animelon.com/video/5762abf7fc68e08dcd850d84). It sounds Atamadaka to me here, but I'm a beginner so might just be mishearing it.

Comment: @George Oh, the girl is saying なんも rather than なににも or なんにも (yet another subtitle mistake). And this なんも is pronounced as heiban to my ears. [This question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/94884/5010) applies perfectly.

Comment: Thanks. It's frustrating that OJAD still seems to get it wrong even with なんも :( And [なん](https://jpdb.io/vocabulary/2846738/%E4%BD%95/%E3%81%AA%E3%82%93?lang=english#a) still shows as only Atamadaka in my dictionary. This seems like a super common word to me so it's surprising to see the official resources getting them wrong.

Comment: Do you know if this is a general pattern for a whole class of words (negative polarity making them switch to Heiban)? Or is it just specific to 何も? According to that answer you linked, someone mentioned it also happens with 誰も.

Comment: @George Not all NPIs are heiban (ちっとも is an NPI but not heiban). As for 何も, it has [this usage](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/47789/5010).