# What does なんてからっきし mean in this sentence?

Tags: sentence, adverbs, reading-comprehension

[image]

からっきし  means
"quite; utterly; (not) at all; completely; wholly; entirely; totally; altogether​" however I'm not sure how it's being used here?

The character gets asked what exactly he thinks is on the the new product, and he answers it's likely there is a speaker on it, which allows it to broadcast sounds. The answer is correct.

He appears to be saying that he's ぼっとしてて　地味っぽくて and he's also making a face like (みたいな顔) that "says"

機械なんてからっきし~

My guess either he's saying the face is... machine like or he saying that the face shows he doesn't understand how that is a machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

からっきし is one of the Japanese [negative-polarity items (NPI)](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/16060/5010). Just like 全然, さっぱり, 少しも and so on can imply negation without saying ない, just saying からっきし would mean "awfully bad", "none", "terrible", etc. The `(not)` enclosed in parentheses is an indicator that it's an NPI.

> ぼーっとしてて、地味っぽくて、「機械なんてからっきし～」みたいな顔して、やるなあ！
>
> Despite your spaced-out, plain look and I'm-totally-clueless-about-machines kind of expression, you really pulled it off!

Answer (score 0):

The verb that the adverb からっきし modifies is omitted, but it would be 知らない or 分からない in this context.