# Using 全然 with a positive pejorative

Tags: words

So far, I know that in proper speech, 全然 should be used with negative verbs such as 全然出来ません or in expressions such as 全然だめ or 全然違う. I am curious about the second type of usage. In that case, 全然 is used with a positive verb that has a negative meaning or pejorative meaning. Is this a generally acceptable usage of the word, for example in these expressions that I just made up:

- 全然悪い(extremely bad),  全然無駄(totally useless), or 全然絶望(total despair).

I have never heard 全然 being used like this other than with だめ/違う so I was curious whether these are acceptable or not.

Would they fall under slang usage? for example as discussed in:
[全然 {ぜんぜん} with positive adjective / na-adjective](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/794/%E5%85%A8%E7%84%B6-%E3%81%9C%E3%82%93%E3%81%9C%E3%82%93-with-positive-adjective-na-adjective/796#796)

Comment: In response to "全然 should be used with negative verbs", see: http://www.nikkei.com/article/DGXBZO37057770W1A201C1000000/

Comment: 全然 in Chinese just means "completely". There's nothing inherently negative in its kanji origins; probably a case of Japanese using 全然 in mostly negative contexts due to certain idiomatic expressions, and prescriptivists coming out to forbid its use in positive expressions.

Comment: What is the difference between your question and question 794 which you linked to?

Comment: In those days Japanese younglings uses 全然 also for positive things. Such as; 全然美味しい. But can't say that grammar is correct, they are just using.

Comment: indeed 全然美味しい is widely used.

Comment: Even Japanese dictionary such as the 広辞苑 tell you that 「全然: ①《名》全くその通りであるさま。②《副》(1)全ての点で。すっかり(2)[下に打消の言い方や否定的意味の語を伴って]全く。まるで(3)[俗な用法で、肯定的にも使う]全く。非常に」 The word 全く sums up these meanings.

Answer (score 3):

全然悪い is the positive assertion that something is really bad. But by being a positive assertion, the construction falls under slang, at least for now. (@snailplane's link says that the use of 全然 was restricted to negative statements only in the 昭和 20ies, i.e. around 1950.)

Similarly for your creations 全然無駄 and 全然絶望.

全然悪い feels like 全然いい, that is "slangy", whereas 全然よくない and 全然悪くない sound like "proper" Japanese.

It appears that 全然だめ and 全然違う, albeit being strictly speaking "positive" statements, are accepted exceptions, presumably, because 違う is a roundabout way of denying what is being said (and maybe だめ is a roundabout way of saying よくない).

Answer (score 3):

It is not correct to say 全然 is used only in the negative context.

There are many examples of affirmative usage of 全然:

> [自己]{じこ}の[主觀的空想]{しゅかんてきくうそう}を[消磨]{しょうま}し[盡]{つく}して[全然]{ぜんぜん}[物]{もの}と[一致]{いっち}したる[處]{ところ}に、[反つ]{かえっ}て[自己]{じこ}の[眞要求]{しんようきゅう}を[滿足]{まんぞく}し[眞]{しん}の[自己]{じこ}を[見]{み}る[事]{こと}ができるのである。
>
> [快樂論者]{かいらくろんしゃ}の[いふ]{いう}[樣]{よう}に[人間]{にんげん}が[全然]{ぜんぜん}[自己]{じこ}の[快樂]{かいらく}を[求]{もと}めて[居]{い}ると[いふ]{いう}のは[頗]{すこぶ}る[穿]{うが}ち[得]{え}たる[眞理]{しんり}の[樣]{よう}であるが、[反つ]{かえっ}て[事實]{じじつ}に[遠ざかつ]{とおざかっ}たものである。
>
> [氏]{し}に[從へ]{したがえ}ば[人性]{じんせい}は[全然]{ぜんぜん}[惡]{あく}[であつて]{であって}[弱肉強食]{じゃくにくきょうしょく}が[自然]{しぜん}の[状態]{じょうたい}である。
>
> [唯]{ただ}[觀念成立]{かんねんせいりつ}の[先在的法則]{せんざいてきほうそく}の[範圍内]{はんいない}に[於]{おい}て、[而]{しか}も[觀念結合]{かんねんけつごう}に[二つ]{ふたつ}[以上]{いじょう}の[途]{みち}があり、[此等]{これら}の[結合]{けつごう}の[強度]{きょうど}が[強迫的]{きょうはくてき}ならざる[場合]{ばあい}に[於]{おい}てのみ、[全然]{ぜんぜん}[選擇]{せんたく}の[自由]{じゆう}を[有]{ゆう}するのである。
>   [心理學者]{しんりがくしゃ}は[内外]{ないがい}と[いふ]{いう}[樣]{よう}に[區別]{くべつ}をするが[意識現象]{いしきげんしょう}としては[全然]{ぜんぜん}[同一]{どういつ}の[性質]{せいしつ}を[具へ]{そなえ}て[居]{い}るのである。
>   [獨]{ひと}り[人間]{にんげん}に[於]{おい}て[純粹持續]{じゅんすいじぞく}は[全然]{ぜんぜん}[物質]{ぶっしつ}に[打]{う}ち[勝つ]{かっ}て[自由]{じゆう}の[域]{いき}に入ることができたのである。
>
> *from* [西田]{にしだ}[幾多郎]{きたろう} 「ベルクソンの[純粹持續]{じゅんすいじぞく}」
>
> ---
>
> [何故]{なぜ}ならば、[若]{も}しも『[法]{ほう}』が[全]{また}く[伸縮]{しんしゅく}しない[固定的]{こていてき}なものであり、[又]{また}[之]{これ}を[運用]{うんよう}する[人間]{にんげん}が[之]{これ}を[全然]{ぜんぜん}[固定的]{こていてき}なものとして[取扱つ]{とりあつかっ}たとすれば、[世]{よ}の[中]{なか}の『[矛盾]{むじゅん}』した『[我儘勝手]{わがままかって}』な[人間]{にんげん}は[必]{かなら}ずや『[一體]{いったい}[法]{ほう}は[何]{なん}の[爲]{た}めに[存]{そん}するのか？』と[云]{ゆ}うて『[法]{ほう}』を[疑ふ]{うたがう}[でせう]{でしょう}。
>
> *from* [末廣]{すえひろ}[嚴太郎]{いずたろう} 「[嘘]{うそ}の[効用]{こうよう}」
>
> ---
>
> [其]{そ}の[道中]{どうちゅう}の[宿場]{しゅくば}の[樣]{よう}に[なつて]{なって}、[假名]{かな}で[書]{か}いたものが[行は]{おこなわ}れるのであります。[中]{なか}に[全然]{ぜんぜん}[國語]{こくご}に[なつた]{なった}ものもある。
>
> *from* [森]{もり}[林太郎]{りんたろう}([森]{もり}[鴎外]{おうがい}) 「[假名遣]{かなづかい}に[關]{かん}する[意見]{いけん}」
>
> ---
>
> [全然]{ぜんぜん}[自發的]{じはつてき}に、[即]{すなわ}ち[少]{すこ}しも[軍部]{ぐんぶ}や[官僚]{かんりょう}の[使嗾]{しそう}を[受]{う}けずに、[さう]{そう}した[小政黨]{しょうせいとう}を[形成]{けいせい}して[行つ]{おこなっ}た。
>
> [又]{また}[或]{あ}る[事項]{じこう}は[全然]{ぜんぜん}[一定]{いってい}の[機關]{きかん}の[專決]{せんけつ}に[委]{ゆだ}ねられて[ゐ]{い}る。
>
> [即]{すなわ}ちそれは[内縁]{ないえん}を[全然]{ぜんぜん}[婚姻]{こんいん}と[同等]{どうとう}[視]{し}し、[苟]{いやしく}も[同棲]{どうせい}・[家計共同]{かけいきょうどう}・[相互扶助]{そうごふじょ}・[子]{こ}の[共同養育]{きょうどうよういく}[等]{など}の[事實]{じじつ}あれば、[たとへ]{たとえ}[屆出]{とどけで}はなくとも[二人]{ふたり}は[法律上]{ほうりつじょう}の[夫婦]{ふうふ}となり、[夫婦]{ふうふ}としてのあらゆる[權利義務]{けんりぎむ}を[帶有]{たいゆう}するに[至]{いた}ると、[定]{たしか}めて[ゐ]{い}るのである。
>
> *from* [栗生]{くりゅう}[武夫]{たけお} 「[一法學者]{いちほうがくしゃ}の[嘆息]{たんそく}」
>
> ---
>
> [乃]{すなわ}ち、[人類]{じんるい}はこの[滅亡]{めつぼう}を[免]{まぬが}れ、この[墮落]{だらく}から[回復]{かいふく}することの[爲]{た}めには、[一切]{いっさい}の[近代的]{きんだいてき}な[思想]{しそう}や、[傾向]{けいこう}や、[精神]{せいしん}を[捨]{す}てて、[全然]{ぜんぜん}[新]{あたら}しいもの、[謂は]{いわ}ば[超近代的]{ちょうきんだいてき}なものを[取]{と}らなければならぬ。
>
> *from* [生田]{いくた}[長江]{ちょうこう} - 「[近代派]{きんだいは}」と「[超近代派]{ちょうきんだいは}」との[戰]{たたかい}

Note that the furigana above are meant to aid the modern reader, they do not reflect the historical kana usage.