# Does 決して always mean "never" even if the verb is negative?

Tags: translation

So I saw this on chat on a gacha game I'm playing.

> 正式触媒も無くかの刀匠を引き当てるほどの奇跡を
>
> 忘れることなど決して

My understanding of this. "It was a miracle for me to summon her without an official catalyst, I'll never forget that."

So I looked up what 決して. I found this on context.reverso.net

> アーロンは決して横たわらない　ゴードンさん

Is the use of "決して" here different? The first example doesn't have the negation yet both examples seem to mean "never".

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/16060/5010

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> **忘れることなど決して**

決して doesn't mean what English "never" means, on its own. It is an adverbial phrase paired with negation, much like "**absolutely** not". Unlike English where most emphatic elements are either shared among positive, question, and negative expressions (if at all / why at all / not at all) or already fused with negative words (nothing / never / none), Japanese has many such freestanding words exclusively serve negative sentences (and [using in positive sentences could be blamed being bad grammar](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/794/7810)). As a result, we can still imply negation even we omit the negation element itself.

> 全然。 *(Not) at all.*
>   ちっとも。 *(Not) a bit.*
>   別に。 *(Not) particular; whatever.*

決して is not a word frequently seen in isolation (not a very colloquial word either), but perfectly understandable whenever it is.